# How to show hidden textbox on dropdown selectedindex chnged event?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a registration form on my school project website. I have given a dropdown menu for security questions and if user wants to type his own question he/she can select other and then a textbox will show which I've set `visible=false` by default.

I tried with this code but it is not working is there anything that I'm missing.

```
protected void selectques_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selectques.Text == "Other")
    {
        alterquestion.Visible = true;
    }   
}
```

DropdownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selectques" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectques_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>Select a question?</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> What is your pet name?</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Who is your first teacher?</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Which is your favourite movie?</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Whom you like most in your life?</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Hidden TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="alterquestion" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="250px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DropDownList.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx) property gives you `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList`. but as per your list items there is no value field

you need to check `selectques.SelectedItem.Text` property to find your ListItem or you can add value field to your list items.

```
<asp:ListItem
    Text="Other"
    Value="Other"
/>
```

**Edit**:

set DropDownList AutoPostBack as true

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="selectques" AutoPostBack= "True" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectques_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: have yo set AutoPostBack="True" ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Actually I don't know how to handle that event.

Comment: Have I set it into ListItem or in TextBox?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use:

```
if (selectques.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
```

That should do the trick